# C - sprintf printing variable name

Tags: c, string, printf

for some reason sprintf prints the name of my char array whose contents I want to append a string to, rendering the result useless. It looks okay, and should work, only it doesn't.
Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR "ST%d"
#define MAX_MSG 80 

 char name[MAX_MSG+1] ;


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
printf("Before: %s\n",name); //--debug
    sprintf(name,STR,1); //format by 1
    printf("After: %s\n",name);
}
```

This then gives me:

```
Before: name
After: nameST1
```

from the little I know this is supposed to give me

```
Before: 
After: ST1
```

Please help.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [Problem is not in this code sample.](http://ideone.com/jvLhkv)

Answer (score 3):

Your first `printf` invoke [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because you didn't init your buffer.

You can do:

```
chat name[50] = {0};
```

Or using [memset](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memset.htm) reset the whole array:

```
memset (name, 0x00, sizeof(name));
```

About the second `printf` I suppose you are not posting your real code. So post it because of the posted code cannot result in `nameST1` as second `printf`

Comment: I still have the same results with that

Comment: @i_use_the_internet Then you didn't post your real code.

Comment: I was editing: post the rieal code. The posted one cannot print nameST1

Comment: @i_use_the_internet maybe the code you are running is not the code you posted. That would explain why your changes don't change the output of your program. Maybe you should post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `printf` expects a `NUL` terminated string. Uninitialized local variable contains garbage data so no `NUL` termination guaranteed (and may perhaps contain values that printf b0rk on). Say you'd call another function instead that looks at the decimal value for each char (and you provide the length of the array) then that would be perfectly fine and would not invoke undefined behaviour. Perhaps clarify the answer a bit?

Comment: `chat name[50] = {0};` ?? OP used a static global, which is initialised to 0. (But OP edited after you answered).

Comment: Yes I just saw that sorry, reversed vote.

Answer (score 2):

The `char name[]` can contain garbage values. Either use memset or initialize as shown.

```
char name[50];
memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
```

or use

```
char name[50] = {0};
```

Comment: No, it wouldn't "do the work". It would work incorrectly the second time you call the function, and also make the code thread-unsafe.

Comment: @Jite If the array was global it was already zeroed, due to bss. So what I ment is that declar it as static has no effects on the array values.

Comment: @LPs If it's global or local static makes no difference as you say. However you specifically wrote that "local static is not bss allocated" which is wrong :)